# What terminology am I looking for to scale like this?

Tags: linear-algebra

Can anyone tell me if there is a simple solution to get a percentage total to scale at a different rate depending on the value?

I have a scale which was laid out nicely like this:

[image: Original scale]

And matched simply with (php):

```
$percentage = ( $referrals / $max ) * 100;
```

But now I've been asked to make it spaced evenly so 5 is 25%, 10 is 50%, 25 is 75% and 50 is 100%:

[image: New scale]

As you can see 25% doesn't map correctly with the initial formula I was using.

I feel like there is a simple solution for this but I don't know what term to use to research further. Please can somebody point me in the right direction?

Comment: A logarithmic scale will produce an evenly spaced scale with the values 3.625,7.25,12.5,25,50  (the next value is twice the one before), for example.

Comment: I think it is better to use a piecewise approximation to the curve that passes through the points $(0,0)$, $(5,25)$, $(10,50)$, $(25,75)$, and $(50,100)$.

Comment: @n74 I think that's what I've done (not a mathematician).  `$percentage = 100; if($referrals < 50) { $percentage = 75; }` and so on down in blocks. So it only changes when the threshold is exceeded, otherwise it shows which stage you have currently met.

Answer (score 0):

**Linear interpolation**

If $referral\leq 10$:

$percentage = 5\times referrals$

If $10<referral\leq 25$:

$percentage = \frac {5\times referrals + 100} {3}$

If $25<referral\leq50$:

$percentage = referrals +50$

[image]

p.s.: You can notice my lagrange attempt in the upper left cornerI would advise against using Lagrange, you would need to add points anyways othrwise it will give you a polynome that decreases on some parts of the interval